# wp_list_comments returning empty

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to remove the default comments/reviews from the WooCommerce product page and replace them with my own.

Removing them was easy as removing them from the hooks that call them.  However putting them back is more difficult than I thought it would be.  I am actually removing the tabs as well - just want the reviews at the bottom of the page.

In the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook I am calling a function that calls the wp_list_comments function.  What I find odd (or simply do not understand why) is that the wp_list_comments function only retrieves the comments if I add the per_page argument.

I have tested it with a custom callback (that only var_dumps the comment object) and the woocommerce-comments callback.  Both work as long as the 'per_page' argument is supplied.

Is this normal behaviour?  When I look at the woocommerce template single-product-reviews.php I can see that they are calling wp_list_comments as such....

```
<?php wp_list_comments( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_review_list_args', array( 'callback' => 'woocommerce_comments' ) ) ); ?>
```

They are only passing the callback argument (I cannot find any filters that are adding any addtional arguments)

Should wp_list_comments be able to be called without arguments and retrieve the comments/reviews for the current product?

Comment: Hi Chris, can you add the most important code :) the hook and the function that you call with that hook? Thx

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Turns out that I wasn't calling the comment template correctly (or at all).  I was able to get it working.  Cheers